# How to create a nodejs instance to run cron jobs at set schedule?

Tags: node.js, cron, npm, cron-task

I need to create a nodejs "server" which wont actually serve any assets or content, but will just run some scheduled job to fetch contents from one database and update another database. The schedule of the job should be configurable and should be able to cancel the job at any time. Basically what I need is to run a node script periodically. In past, I have created node/express projects, but I am having a hard time understanding how to implement such a node instance which will run on a remote machine and how to start or terminate it. I found a npm package called "node-schedule" which runs the job periodically, but how to put this package on a remote machine instance and run it?

One possibility that was considered was to schedule a cron job on remote machine which will execute "node updateDB.js" on set schedule, but it is a requirement to keep everything in node package and not depend on cron.

Comment: A [Google search for "node cron"](https://www.google.com/search?q=node+cron) turns up a whole bunch of modules that support scheduling an activity to run sometime in the future from within node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for ssh. 
Personally I wouldn't use NodeJS for this, this should be pretty trivial to do, with Node or otherwise, not sure why you are stuck, honestly. I have nothing against Node, but I don't see why it would be necessary for this task, but certainly you could use it for such a thing.

EDIT: After reading your comment I'm convinced someone thinks Node is a good tool for this task. I guess I don't understand where you are stuck. What part are you stuck on? 
I think you should be able to puzzle this out pretty fast. The link below should be enough to put this together. http://book.mixu.net/node/ch9.html
If you need to execute ad hoc commands on a remote server you could use Node to call an Ansible playbook, in that case you'll need to share the public ssh key on the target instance(s) with the instance issuing the commands. There are other ways to skin this cat, but based on the information given, that's how I'd do it. I'd use Node and Ansible (requires python) + SSH.

Oh neato, maybe if I were forced to use NodeJS I'd use this package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-exec
Did you find an answer to your problem? Share it here.

Comment: Its not just plain db replication as data gets processed before updating second db. The reason for requirement to use node is for code reuse. There are already scripts in another nodejs project which are already fetching data, processing it using some javascript and updating it in different db. Those scripts will then be reused in this project for easier maintenance.

Comment: I see, and I thought that might be the case.